# Application for google adsense rejected twice due to Unacceptable site content

Tags: google, google-adsense

I have a technical blog site and frequently I add technical articles.

I applied for Google Adsense but my application rejected, twice in fact. The issue reported both times was non-acceptable site content. I read the content policy by Google and found nothing that would indicate that the content I have on my blog is unacceptable to them.

Why are my next steps?

Comment: Btw nice looking.

Comment: It could simply be that the previous owner of your domain had questionable content. Did you dig wayback / cache to check?

Comment: Hello,

I have a huge site www.indianchamps.com , But google rejected my request please can you suggest why this happend. I have spend around 1 lack in making the website but no returns by google, I have created more than 20,000 pages.

Please please some 1 help me..

Comment: I'm sure 90% of sites in India run on bought Adsense account and in fact Google implicitly allows cheap sites, given the level of public and business atomosphere in India. All sites have it(except for new ones like yours). Check MFA sites: customercarecontacts.com and customercareinfo.in . But they're earning non-stop... customercareinfo.in was banned once but it managed again to get another account. In India rules are very different.

Answer (score 4):

I think the info links advertising could be the main problem. Regardless of Adsense, I would personally stay away from using those because they are annoying and put people off the site. Everything else looks OK to me.

Comment: +1 for infolinks advertising. I hate these. Apparently the phrase President Obama means I want to go on a holiday?!

Answer (score 1):

I searched over your site for keywords that might be banned, but I did not find any bad keywords. Just check whether any post on your site contains same contents which are already published somewhere else.

Do you have any image which conflict copyright issue?

I didn't found any footer on your site contains copyright disclaimer. It might be because your site is not loaded successfully. And gave some error. you will found `-->` somewhere on your site. Just check it against w3c compatibility.

Comment: Thanks, i will add a footer and a copy right notice. I have a few posts on this blog which are also present on on of my other blogs too. Do you think that can be one of the issues ? Also i have a line at the bottom of my posts which says that in case you like this post please share it with others by clicking the links below, do you think that might be causing this issue ? Is it fine to have infolinks ads along with google adsense ?

Comment: link you provided for sharing is not a issue. but the posts which are similar can create a problem. You can have multiple ads from different adsense. There is no problem in this

Answer (score 1):

I would send Google an email and ask them specifically why you were rejected.

I worked with a client for a few months in setting up their Google Base feed for selling products online. They were rejected 10 times in a row (each time for different reasons). But Google was very quick to reply and give specific reasons as to why they were rejected.

Comment: For for Indians it won't be same. I submitted my site thrice and subsequently a bot was rejecting it even on Sundays after couple of hours.